# Write a program that prints the number of times the string 'bob' occurs in s? where s is pre-defined

Tags: python

I tried to write a code for this. But it gives me right answer only few times where 'bob' doesnt come simultaneously....

code:
print s.count('bob')

Comment: Can we get an example of s?

Comment: Is `bobob` considered as 1 or 2 bob's ? :)

Comment: bobob considered as 2 bob's

Comment: You shouldn't use `count` to count overlapping sub-strings: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count

Answer (score 4):

use lookahead in regex to find overlapping occurences

```
import re
len(re.findall('(?=bob)',s))
```

Comment: This probably covers all the edge cases. Thanks!

Comment: @nishanthchava It does :)

Answer (score 3):

This *could* be as simple as:

```
from re import findall

len(findall("(?=bob)", s))
```

**Example(s)**:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> s = "Helo bob; I'm bob"
>>> len(findall("(?=bob)", s))
2
>>> s = "Hello Fred!"
>>> len(findall("(?=bob)", s))
0
>>> s = "bobbobboul"
>>> len(findall("(?=bob)", s))
2
>>> len(findall("(?=bob)", s))
2
```

Comment: lets say 's' is bobbobboul for which this code gives me wrong output.

Comment: Fixed to take care of that *edge-case*.

Comment: In your first example itself , you are getting wrong output right ? It contains 1 'bob' where as you are getting 2 as output*

Comment: Whoops yes; another edge-case!

Comment: @JamesMills this gives `1` for `bobob` since the regex `bob` consumes text, use lookahead to match without consuming text

Comment: @alfasin didn't notice that answer turn up! My bad *whistles innocently*

Comment: @JonClements your bad whistles ? (just kidding :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to count overlapping sub-strings, you'll have to implement an auxiliary function ([`string.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) won't do it for you):

```
def count(string, sub):
    counter = 0
    while sub in string:
        counter += 1
        index = string.index(sub)
        string = string[index+1:]
    return counter

print count("bobob", "bob") # 2
```

Another option is to use regex-lookahead as Pruthvi Raj suggested.