# Write a program that prints the number of times the string contains a substring

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
s = "bobobobobobsdfsdfbob"
count = 0 
for x in s : 
    if x == "bob" : 
       count += 1
print count
```

i want to count how many bobs in string s, the result if this gives me 17 
what's wrong with my code i'm newbie python.

Comment: I do not get the answer `17`, I get `0` in python 2.x. In python 3.x I get an error, which can be corrected by using `print(count)` rather than `print count`. Please make sure your code runs and make sure you are telling us the actual problem.

Comment: What is the answer you're expecting for the string you gave? What is the answer you expect for a shorter string like `bobob`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a program that prints the number of times the string 'bob' occurs in s? where s is pre-defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972133/write-a-program-that-prints-the-number-of-times-the-string-bob-occurs-in-s-wh)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting matching substrings in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418432/counting-matching-substrings-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are looping overt the string, the throwaway variable will hold the characters, so in your loop `x` is never equal with `bob`.

If you want to count the non-overlaping strings you can simply use `str.count`:

```
In [52]: s.count('bob')
Out[52]: 4
```

For overlapping sub-strings you can use lookaround in regex:

```
In [57]: import re

In [59]: len(re.findall(r'(?=bob)', s))
Out[59]: 6
```

Comment: That only counts substrings if they're completely separate. This depends on whether or not `bobob` should return 1 or 2.

Comment: @merlinpatt Yes, that's another problem, check out the update for one solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.count

for example:

```
s = "bobobobobobsdfsdfbob"
count = s.count("bob")
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving the best solution, just trying to correct your code.

**Understanding what `for each (a.k.a range for)` does in your case**

```
for c in "Hello":
    print c
```

Outputs:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

In each iteration you are comparing a character to a string which results in a wrong answer.
Try something like
(For no overlapping, i.e no span)

```
s = "bobobobobobsdfsdfbob"
w = "bob"
count = 0
i = 0
while i <= len(s) - len(w):
    if s[i:i+len(w)] == w:
        count += 1
        i += len(w)
    else:
        i += 1
print (count)
```

Output:

`Count = 4`

Overlapping

```
s = "bobobobobobsdfsdfbob"
w = "bob"
count = 0
for i in range(len(s) - len(w) + 1):
    if s[i:i+len(w)] == w:
         count += 1
print (count)
```

Output:
`Count = 6`